# Azure Data Factory - How to handle nested Array inside JSON data to import to Blob Storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am creating a pipeline for importing JSON data from a REST source to Blob Storage. 
However, I have a problem because there is a nested array inside the array that contains the main data.

The JSON data is like following:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "<Context>",
  "@odata.nextLink": "<Next Link>",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "<Type>",
      "reportRefreshDate": "2019-05-18",
      "userPrincipalName": "abc@xyz.net",
      "displayName": "abc",
      "isDeleted": false,
      "deletedDate": null,
      "hasExchangeLicense": true,
      "hasOneDriveLicense": true,
      "hasSharePointLicense": true,
      "hasSkypeForBusinessLicense": true,
      "hasYammerLicense": true,
      "hasTeamsLicense": true,
      "exchangeLastActivityDate": "2019-05-17",
      "oneDriveLastActivityDate": null,
      "sharePointLastActivityDate": null,
      "skypeForBusinessLastActivityDate": null,
      "yammerLastActivityDate": null,
      "teamsLastActivityDate": null,
      "exchangeLicenseAssignDate": "2019-03-19",
      "oneDriveLicenseAssignDate": "2018-07-06",
      "sharePointLicenseAssignDate": "2018-07-06",
      "skypeForBusinessLicenseAssignDate": "2018-05-22",
      "yammerLicenseAssignDate": "2018-05-22",
      "teamsLicenseAssignDate": "2018-05-22",
      "assignedProducts": [
        "OFFICE 365 E3",
        "OFFICE 365 E5"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As you could notice here, there is a nested array named "assignedProducts" inside the main array "value"

I defined the schema of the blob storage as following:
[image]

And when I define the mapping between the source and sink, I could not map the nested array, it shows like following:

[image]

To the best of my knowledge, it is possible to make a loop for the array. But for the nested array, it seems to be difficult.

Could anybody suggest me what I should do to handle the nested array? It would be even great if converting this array into string or something else.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I'm having a similar problem - did you find a solution? I can get the nested array to output the whole array as a string, but just want extract one value from the nested array and can't find a way to do that in ADF

Comment: I think currently, it is impossible to handle that kind of nesting with the given options. Instead, we could use Azure Function App or Batch Service for handling.

Comment: Thank you - have you raised the issue with Microsoft? If not I’m happy to log a ticket

Comment: This seems to be out of reach with fundamental functions. So I have not, but employed Function App instead for more complicating function.

Comment: Use flatten transformation for array https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-flatten

Answer (score 0):

I simulate some sample data like yours:

```
[  
   {  
      "numberArray":[  
         "1",
         "2",
         "3"
      ],
      "name":"A"
   },
   {  
      "numberArray":[  
         "4",
         "5",
         "6"
      ],
      "name":"B"
   }
]
```

Then I configure my Blob Storage DataSet as below,please set the `File Pattern` as `Array of Objects`.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry bur it seems that you save your data without using any schema and mapping. My problem is when I use Mapping and Schema, I could not handle the nested array inside the main array